# Image as background in video tag in HTML

Tags: html

I am adding object tag in Web Page Editor in Eclipse.It shows object default image in design page but i want to change this image through CSS.
please find my code:

I am adding my css file as class="vd" where i am passing {background:url("myimg.png")}
but this  image is not replacing default image of object.
What is the way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the HTML editor in Eclipse and make the changes there, either inline to the image or applying a class/selector.

Comment: I have added css class and in that class i gave{ background: url("myimg.png")}but its not reflecting over there,Its giving default image of object tag.